# Preserve Case sensitive filename in Dropbox API when updating a file

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I am using code like this:

```
Metadata e = ...;
dbxClient.files().uploadBuilder(e.getPathLower()).withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE).uploadAndFinish(...)
```

which results in losing the case of the filename (e.g. MyFile.txt becomes myfile.txt). This seems obvious as `getPathLower` is returning the lower-case filename.

`Metadata` has another method `getDisplayName()` returning the cased path:

```
 /**
     * The cased path to be used for display purposes only. In rare instances
     * the casing will not correctly match the user's filesystem, but this
     * behavior will match the path provided in the Core API v1, and at least
     * the last path component will have the correct casing. Changes to only the
     * casing of paths won't be returned by {@link
     * DbxUserFilesRequests#listFolderContinue(String)}. This field will be null
     * if the file or folder is not mounted.
     *
     * @return value for this field, or {@code null} if not present.
     */
    public String getPathDisplay() {
        return pathDisplay;
    }
```

I did not want to use this as it says it's for display purposes only.

So, how can I avoid losing the case of the filename correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an existing file for which you have the `Metadata`, you can use the file ID. You can get the file ID using [`FileMetadata.getId`](http://e.getPathLower()%20https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v4.0.1/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/FileMetadata.html#getId--), and then pass that value to the `path` parameter of `uploadBuilder` (instead of `e.getPathLower()`).

Comment: just for reference: the documentation says this is possible in https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.1.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/DbxUserFilesRequests.html#uploadBuilder-java.lang.String-